# no operator "=" matches these operands error

Tags: c++

i have tried this code. I'm getting the error

```
no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are:
std::pair<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char *,
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char>>>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char>>>> = std::pair<std::__cxx11::string *,
std::__cxx11::string *>
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

bool cmp_string(std::string i , std::string j)
{
    return ( i.size() == j.size() );
}

int main()
{
int inputs1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int inputs2[] = {-1,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9};

vector<int> v1(inputs1 ,inputs1+9);
vector<int> v2(inputs2 ,inputs2+9);

pair<vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>::iterator>  position;
/* defining a pair of iterator to the vector of integer */

position = mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin()+2) ;

/* now position.first is an iterator pointing 
to the 5th element in the vector v1 and position.second 
points to the 7th element in the vector v2 */

/* use of compare function */
string s1[] = {"abc", "def", "temp", "testing"};
string s2[] = {"xyz", "emp", "res", "testing"};

pair<string::iterator, string::iterator> position1;

position1 = mismatch(s1, s1+4, s2, cmp_string);
  /* now position2.first is an iterator pointing
to the 3rd element in s1 and position2.second points 
to the 3rd element in the s2 */
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `inputs1+9` is *two* steps beyond the end of the 8-element array. Remember that array indexes are zero-based, with an 8 element array having indexes from `0` to `7`. So the "end" iterator is `inputs1 + 8`. Besides, you don't even need those arrays, you can initialize the vectors directly instead: `std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };`

Comment: s1 and s2 are string arrays, iterators of these arrays are string*, not string::iterator. Better use auto position1 = ...

Comment: By the way I suggest you learn about the C++ automatic type-deduction for variable definitions, which makes it easy to work around the problem here: `auto position1 = mismatch(s1, s1 + 4, s2, cmp_string);`

Comment: Is there a reason you did not just fill your vectors directly? i.e.  `std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};`. Similarly for the string arrays further down your code. C++11 onwards have initializer lists which permit directly filling standard containers.

Comment: Your first `mismatch` call is going to run off the end of `v2` since you made both of them the same size and then started 2 ahead in the second. I assume you didn't mean to make them the same size, but that's another reason to initialize them directly.

Comment: Instead of doing `x, x + size`, prefer `std::begin(x), std::end(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem was identified by @S.M., `position1` is not the correct type. There are other code improvements that you should consider:

1. Use automatic type deduction. @Someprogrammerdude suggests using `auto position1 ...` which is available in C++11 onwards.
2. @Evg suggests you use [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) instead of `x, x+size` pairs. This removes explicit size parameters and, therefore, reduces the probability of programmer errors because the compiler or runtime code determines the size for you.
3. As @Someprogrammerdude and I suggested, you can use initializer lists in C++11 onwards so you can populate a `std::vector` directly.
4. Do not use a blanket `using namespace std;` statement in your code. Bringing too much into the global namespace could cause name conflicts in larger code bases.